# eclipse synchronized git IllegalCharsetNameException:-1

Tags: eclipse, egit

Eclipse platform: version:4.3.2
Build id:M20140221-1700

Team>>Synchronize Workspace, it can show files I change and other people committed.
But when checked the changes, it opened blank file window. Error found in .metedata>>.log. (Picture below)
**java.nio.charset.illegalcharsetnameexception:-1**
**Why get -1 for the charsetname. How to change it ?**

jar version: jgit_3.2.0, egit.ui_3.2.0, egit.core_3.2.0
But for any changed file,right click and compared with HEAD Revision，it can compare normally.
And other projects on the same workspace don't have such problems.
[image]

Comment: Your Eclipse is so old, it was already outdated five years ago. Before asking, please make sure that you are not using outdated software for no reason.

Comment: Use it more than one year, just curious why doesn't work suddenly.  I will try to get the latest version, thank you. I can only post the error msg by picture, can you guess how strict net limitation work office has.

Comment: It might also be a misconfiguration of a Git repository or a configuration that confuses JGit (maybe something new in Git that wasn't there at that time). Are you sure it's `-1` and not `-|`? Have you checked your Git configuration for an unusual encoding?